# Match joined sentences by period with Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Using Ruby. Here's a sample text:

> The ride costs E£4. It's worth having a torch to illuminate badly lit
>   areas.Most tombs described here are usually open to visitors. They are
>   listed in the order that they are found when entering the site. The
>   best source of information about the tombs, their decoration and
>   history is the Theban Mapping Project
>   (www.thebanmappingproject.com).Tomb of Ramses VII (KV 1) Near the main
>   entrance is the small, unfinished tomb of Ramses VII (1136-1129 BC).
>   Only 44.3m long - short for a royal tomb because of Ramses' sudden
>   death - it consists of a corridor, a burial chamber and an unfinished
>   third chamber.

I tried the following, but it matches together with the next capital letter:

```
/\.[A-Z]/ #=> matches .T instead of .
```

I want to:

- match the period `.` in `.Tomb` only - any dot that is followed by a capital letter,
- not match `.3` in `44.3m`,
- not match `.t` or `.c` in `www.thebanmappingproject.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried?

```
/(\.)(?=[A-Z])/g
```

it will match any dot followed by capital letters

Comment: /g modifier will make this match not only for the first dot, but all dots followed by capital letters, in your example, it will match for 2 dots, not just one

Comment: @Victor and Sirus: Ruby does not support `/g`. Only `/i`, `/m`, `/x`, `/o`. See the section "Options" in the doc for [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html).

Comment: Without `/g` you could use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan), but `text.scan /(\.)(?=[A-Z])/ #=> [["."], ["."]]` is of dubious value. (Same result if `/g` is included.)

Answer (score 1):

If `text` is your string,

```
text.scan(/(\.)[A-Z]/).flatten
  #=> [".", "."]
```

returns what you've asked for, but is that really what you want? It might be preferable to write

```
text.scan(/\.[A-Z]/)
  #=> [".M", ".T"]
```

or

```
text.gsub(/\.(?=[A-Z])/).with_object([]) { |_,a| a << Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first }
  #=> [75, 342]

text[75, 20]
  #=> ".Most tombs describe" 
text[342, 20]
  #=> ".Tomb of Ramses VII "
```

(`20` is arbritary).

The use of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) here is interesting. I've used `gsub` because, without a block, it returns an enumerator, which I need to chain with [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object). The value returned by `gsub` is in fact discarded. Since [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) without a block does not return an enumerator, to use it I'd have to write:

```
a = []
text.scan(/\.(?=[A-Z])/) { a << Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first }
a #=> [75, 342]
```

which would hardly be the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.You just need a parenthesis to match the dot and the global modifier g to match EVERY dot followed by a capital letter, not just the first:

```
/(\.)[A-Z]/g
```

Comment: The capital letter following the period is not to be part of the match. That's why Sirius used a positive lookahead for the capital letter.